# RunTimeException in Android espresso when selecting spinner in dialog

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an activity where some dialog is openend. On this dialog there is a spinner. I want to select a specific value in this spinner, but I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Otherwise, something is seriously wrong. Selected Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7017bc1, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7017bc1, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#3 ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1280, height=752, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
.All Roots:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ae6d4cb, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@920a4a8, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=1002, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(91,111)(509x113) gr=#10000033 sim=#1 ty=1002 fl=#1860200 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10302e3 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) (manual)}, decor-view-string=PopupDecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=509, height=113, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ae6d4cb, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ae6d4cb, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=2, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#3 ty=2 fl=#1800002 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10303e6 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=616, height=490, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7017bc1, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7017bc1, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#3 ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1280, height=752, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:99)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:69)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:23)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:68) .....
```

My code:

```
 protected void selectSpinnerValue(int id, String value) {
    onView(withId(id)).perform(click());
    onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(value))).perform(click());
}
```

The exception happens on the line onData(allOf....)

How can I tell espresso to look in the dialog?

Comment: Try using isPlatformPopup(), it will match the window that spinner is rendered in.

Comment: Thank you, how do I use this? onData(isPlatformPopup(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class))))) is not working

Comment: I'm writing from my mobile now, I think the onData was OK and espresso is throwing the exception when executing the onView code and something like:     onView(withId(id)).inRoot(isPlattormPopup()).perform(click()); should work. Give it a try, I saw this exception before.

Comment: Hi, the line onView(withId(id)).perform(click()) works well, I got the exception on:  onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(value))).perform(click());

Comment: It seems that isPlatformPopup() is not working in combination with onData()... Try to use it with onView()! -> See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40015436/2531709

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error when I tried to match an item inside a spinner inside a dialog-fragment. 
This helped:

```
onView(withText(value)).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());
```

Comment: This will not work for items that are scrolled offscreen.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(value)))
    .inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());
```

Comment: Your solution didnt quite work for me but I managed to get it working this way. I think this is a better approach if you just want to click on a specific item and move on:

onData(anything()).atPosition(position).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I tried to match a text inside an alert dialog. This helped:

```
onView(withText(text)).inRoot(RootMatchers.isDialog()).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on Pixel 2 XL with **Android Pie** and I have to add

```
.inRoot(isPlatformPopup())
```

when for EditText appears credentials autofill spinner
[image]