# Espresso always fails when trying to select item in spinner

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, ui-testing

I tried to select an item from a simple spinner, but it always failed. I can click the spinner and it shows the list. But when I try to select even the first option, it always throw `indexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:385)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getItem(Spinner.java:1010)
at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:801)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.AdapterViewProtocols$StandardAdapterViewProtocol.getDataInAdapterView(AdapterViewProtocols.java:90)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.AdapterDataLoaderAction.perform(AdapterDataLoaderAction.java:79)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:360)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:251)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:64)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:157)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Tests ran to completion.
```

I tried some methods ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575255/set-spinner-item-with-espresso), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920141/runtimeexception-in-android-espresso-when-selecting-spinner-in-dialog)) with the same result. Here's my current implementation:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click())
        Thread.sleep(7000)

        onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(String::class.java)))).atPosition(0).perform(click())
        Thread.sleep(7000)
        onView(withId(R.id.selected)).check(matches(withText(instanceForTest)))
```

Comment: I think your adapter returns other type of objects instead of String, could you paste your adapter code?

Comment: @Aaron that's also comes up in my mind. But now I use different method and it works. I'll post the answer and please take a look at it if there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the id and the text in the textView:

```
try {

    Thread.sleep(3000)

    onView(withId(R.id.spinner))
            .perform(click())

    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.text_name), withText(instanceForTest)))
            .perform(scrollTo(), click())

    onView(withId(R.id.text_name))
            .check(matches(withText(instanceForTest)))

    Thread.sleep(3000)

    onView(withId(R.id.start)).perform(click())

} catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {

}
```

It might not the best way, but this one works.

Answer (score 1):

Use Barista's method `clickSpinnerItem(R.id.spinner, indexToSelect)`. It works with all kinds of data, no matter which one. In addition, your test will be more readable. Get Barista from https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista

By the way, consider using Barista's sleep method or, if possible, implement your own IdlingResource to make your tests faster and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I use different way and it works now. I'll try to be comfortable with espresso first, before jumping to another library

Comment: Good choice! Barista is just an Espresso wrapper, not a total replacement, but no prob! Just get sure that you read its readme, to avoid getting totally mad when things get wrong with plain Espresso hehehe! Cheers!